# How to store the values of an appended table row in an array variable using onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an ajax function that gets the values from the database and then appends those data to a table. Now, there are instances that there will be 2 or more records from the database that are being retrieved, so 2 or more table rows are also appended.My problem is, how would I able to store those values in an array variable if 2 or more values are appended on the table? Here are the codes. Thank you for the help.

```
$.post("{{ url('create_po') }}", { 'prod_IDs': valArray }, function(data){
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(var i = 0; i < obj.prodval.length; i++){
    txt += "<tr class='info '><td><input type='number' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='0'/>"+
         "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].unit+
         "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].pharmaceutical+
         "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].packaging+
         "</td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='"+obj.prodval[i].price+"' disabled=disabled />"+
         "</td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='0' disabled=disabled />"+
         "</td></tr>";
}
 $("#tbl-po-list").append(txt);
});
```

**Table**

```
<table id="tbl-po-list">
<tbody id="po-create"></tbody>
</table>
```

**Bind Function to get the values onchange**

```
$(function(){

var arrayVar = [];

            $('#tbl-po-list').on( 'change keyup' , 'input[type="number"]' ,function(){

            $(this).val();
            $(this).parents('.info').find('.price').val();
            $(this).parents('.info').find('.total').val());

            });

        });
```

I just dont know how to take a step here. How would I save the values in the array variable "arrayVar" during onchange event? What if there are 2 rows? How would I save it?

**Appended rows sample image**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to use a MV* framework (choose it [here](http://todomvc.com/)) in conjunction with [JS template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store it in an object:

```
var data = {
   qty: $(this).val(),
   price: $(this).parents('.info').find('.price').val(),
   total: $(this).parents('.info').find('.total').val()
}
```

Then when you retrieve it (based upon your image):

```
arrayVar[0].price // 45
arrayVar[1].price // 12
```

Comment: arrayvar[0].price and arrayVar[1].price have the same value.

Comment: Well each row needs to be an item in the array and it pushes the data into the correct slot.

Comment: just missing arrayVar.push(data);

Comment: I have revised the table right now. The packaging column now requires an input but I only get blank value of it after putting the quantity value first. It only works unless the value of packaging is inputted first before setting the quantity value. How would I address this problem? Please help. Thanks a lot.